# Almalinux 8.5 - Log Files (secure, messages, cron, etc) are not populating / blank?

Tags: logs, rsyslog

Running Almalinux 8.5, `rsyslog` version 8.2102.0-5.el8.  A few weeks ago all my system logs (`secure`, `messages`, `cron`...) began to show 0 byte values.  Turns out they are not receiving messages from the journal anymore.  Program specific logs (such as Apache) are working fine.

Thus far I've started / restarted both `rsyslog` and `systemd-journald` - both confirmed running.  Rotated logs - nothing. Tried to see if it's a permissions issue:

Ran: `ls -ld /var/log`

```
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4096 Nov 28 02:42 /var/log
```

Also ran: `ls -l /var/log`

```
total 30076
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root               57930 Oct  1 11:16 almalinux-deploy.debug.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root              340552 Oct  1 11:16 almalinux-deploy.log
-rw-rw----  1 root     utmp            11740416 Nov 30 15:32 btmp
-rw-rw----  1 root     utmp                1536 Oct  6 22:55 btmp-20211101
-rw-------  1 root     root                   0 Nov 28 02:42 cron
-rw-------  1 root     root              856453 Nov  7 02:42 cron-20211107
-rw-------  1 root     root               56894 Nov  7 14:03 cron-20211114
-rw-------  1 root     root                   0 Nov 14 02:42 cron-20211121
-rw-------  1 root     root              158412 Nov 27 09:39 cron-20211128
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root              619845 Nov 30 15:38 dnf.librepo.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root              409954 Nov 30 15:38 dnf.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root             1048575 Nov 18 01:53 dnf.log.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root              168211 Nov 30 15:38 dnf.rpm.log
-rw-------  1 root     root                   0 Nov 17 02:42 dovecot-lmtp-errors.log
-rw-------  1 root     root                4240 Oct  7 15:29 dovecot-lmtp-errors.log-20211009
-rw-------  1 root     root                1424 Oct 21 23:41 dovecot-lmtp-errors.log-20211022
-rw-------  1 root     root                1424 Oct 27 18:02 dovecot-lmtp-errors.log-20211029
-rw-------  1 root     root                1232 Nov  9 10:05 dovecot-lmtp-errors.log-20211110
-rw-------  1 root     root                  85 Nov 16 18:57 dovecot-lmtp-errors.log-20211117
-rw-------  1 root     root                   0 Nov  9 10:03 dovecot-lmtp.log
drwx------  2 mail     mail                4096 Nov 28 02:42 exim
-rw-r-----  1 root     root                 186 Oct  1 11:08 firewalld
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root                1980 Nov 30 15:38 hawkey.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root                 960 Nov  6 06:38 hawkey.log-20211107
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root                3420 Nov 13 23:56 hawkey.log-20211114
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root                3960 Nov 21 02:39 hawkey.log-20211121
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root                3060 Nov 28 00:31 hawkey.log-20211128
drwx--x---  3 apache   root                4096 Nov 30 00:10 httpd
drwxr-sr-x+ 3 root     systemd-journal     4096 Oct  1 11:07 journal
-rw-rw-r--  1 root     utmp              292584 Nov 30 16:00 lastlog
-rw-------  1 root     root               77008 Nov 30 16:16 lfd.log
-rw-------  1 root     root                7480 Nov 28 02:40 lfd.log-20211128.gz
-rw-------  1 root     root                   0 Nov 28 02:42 maillog
-rw-------  1 root     root               94207 Nov  7 01:39 maillog-20211107
-rw-------  1 root     root                7274 Nov  7 14:03 maillog-20211114
-rw-------  1 root     root                   0 Nov 14 02:42 maillog-20211121
-rw-------  1 root     root               10025 Nov 27 09:39 maillog-20211128
-rw-------  1 root     root                 273 Nov 30 15:19 messages
-rw-------  1 root     root            11607290 Nov  7 02:42 messages-20211107
-rw-------  1 root     root              805384 Nov  7 14:03 messages-20211114
-rw-------  1 root     root                   0 Nov 14 02:42 messages-20211121
-rw-------  1 root     root             2458409 Nov 27 09:39 messages-20211128
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root     root                  36 Oct  1 11:53 php-fpm74.log -> /usr/local/php74/var/log/php-fpm.log
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root     root                  36 Oct  1 14:25 php-fpm80.log -> /usr/local/php80/var/log/php-fpm.log
drwx------  2 root     root                4096 Jan 19  2021 private
-rw-------  1 root     root                   0 Nov 10 01:22 pureftpd.log
drwx------  3 root     root                4096 Oct  9 16:51 samba
-rw-------  1 root     root                   0 Nov 28 02:42 secure
-rw-------  1 root     root                5895 Nov  6 04:23 secure-20211107
-rw-------  1 root     root                  67 Nov  7 14:03 secure-20211114
-rw-------  1 root     root                   0 Nov 14 02:42 secure-20211121
-rw-------  1 root     root               12178 Nov 27 09:39 secure-20211128
-rw-------  1 root     root                   0 Nov 28 02:42 spooler
-rw-------  1 root     root                   0 Oct 31 02:42 spooler-20211107
-rw-------  1 root     root                   0 Nov  7 02:42 spooler-20211114
-rw-------  1 root     root                   0 Nov 14 02:42 spooler-20211121
-rw-------  1 root     root                   0 Nov 21 02:42 spooler-20211128
drwx--x--x  2 root     root                4096 Nov 30 00:10 user_logs
-rw-rw-r--  1 root     utmp               71808 Nov 30 16:00 wtmp
```

There is no separate user for rsyslog and everything runs off the root, so this shouldn't be an issue. Also tried deleting `imjournal.state` file and restart journal service - got a bunch of messages from this server's rebuild in early October. journalctl does show recent entries, including failed SSH logins et all, so it's not like the journal service is dead - there's some kind of disconnect going on...

Contents of my `rsyslog.conf` file for reference:

```
#### MODULES ####

module(load="imuxsock"    # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
       SysSock.Use="off") # Turn off message reception via local log socket; 
              # local messages are retrieved through imjournal now.
module(load="imjournal"         # provides access to the systemd journal
       StateFile="imjournal.state") # File to store the position in the journal
#module(load="imklog") # reads kernel messages (the same are read from journald)
#module(load="immark") # provides --MARK-- message capability

# Provides UDP syslog reception
# for parameters see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/imudp.html
#module(load="imudp") # needs to be done just once
#input(type="imudp" port="514")

# Provides TCP syslog reception
# for parameters see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/imtcp.html
#module(load="imtcp") # needs to be done just once
#input(type="imtcp" port="514")

#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Where to place auxiliary files
global(workDirectory="/var/lib/rsyslog")

# Use default timestamp format
module(load="builtin:omfile" Template="RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat")

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
include(file="/etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf" mode="optional")

#### RULES ####

# Log all kernel messages to the console.
# Logging much else clutters up the screen.
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog


# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log
```

I'm sure it's something obvious being overlooked. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? If so, please post it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same on my home server.

I found one possible solution at [System logs are no longer being written to nor are files being created](https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360059952274-System-logs-are-no-longer-being-written-to-nor-are-files-being-created):

```
systemctl restart systemd-journald.socket
systemctl restart systemd-journald
systemctl restart rsyslog
```

This appears to have worked for me for now.  Part of the article also suggests doing `stat /dev/log` to make sure that it's there.  It was for me but I ran the above anyway and now have logging.

Comment: Please don't ask questions in the answer section, that is not how Stack Exchange works. Please take the [tour] to get a better understanding of how the Q&A mechanism works. Your initial question could have been placed as a comment under the OP's question - I have already done this for you as you don't have enough rep yet (50 points is required).

Comment: Perhaps you should read it again.

Answer (score 0):

My logs (mail, messages, etc.) were empty, too. And I could not start rsyslogd. It turned out to be a selinux issue. The following helped. Start with a test:

```
logger -p mail.info "testing maillog"
```

This should create a log entry in the `maillog`. At first it didn't work.

```
getenforce   # -> Enforcing
setenforce 0
getenforce   # -> Permissive
logger -p mail.info "testing maillog"  # works now
setenforce 1
getenforce   # -> Enforcing
```

On another machine I installed AlmaLinux 8 minimal. It was so minimal that rsyslog was not installed. There was a symbolic link from `/etc/systemd/system/syslog.service` to `rsyslog` in `/usr`. The link was broken because rsyslog was not there. I had to say

```
dnf install rsyslog
systemctl enable rsyslog --now
```